# How to extract first component ID from #{cc.clientId}?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, clientid

I neet to get a specific parent component ID in a composite component. I've only found out how to get the entire chain of IDs, namely as I wrote in the title: `#{cc.clientId}`. It delivers (I don't know how they're called) `Id1:Id2:Id3`, but I need only `Id1`, how can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [the `fn:split()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/fn/split.fn.html) for this:

```
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
...

#{fn:split(cc.clientId, ':')[0]}
```

Another way is to use [`UIComponent#getNamingContainer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getNamingContainer%28%29) on the [`UIComponent#getParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getParent%28%29):

```
#{cc.parent.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer.clientId}
```

There may be better ways depending on the concrete functional requirement and the code you have so far, both which are missing in your question. For example, if `Id1` actually refers a `<h:form>`, then you could use `render="@form"` instead in the `<f:ajax>`.

The `Id1:Id2:Id3` is by the way just called the client ID (as you see in generated HTML output). The `Id1` part is actually the component ID (as you see in JSF source code). The prepending of [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) IDs in client ID as in `Id1:Id2:Id3` is also sometimes called woodstocking.